# glass effect with linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm looking for a glass effect with a linear-gradient like in [image]. I've tried several effect and the one that most resembles is:

```
background: linear-gradient(#1f87ab, #004961 50%, #004961 90%);
```

I've also looked at:

[Creating a Two-Color Sharp Gradient on Text With CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002429/creating-a-two-color-sharp-gradient-on-text-with-css3)

[Horizontal sharp background gradient with specific length of first color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918454/horizontal-sharp-background-gradient-with-specific-length-of-first-color/33918557)

But they didn't help

Comment: can you detail more the *glass effect* part?

Comment: Like the buttons in `werc.com`but not in a curve, just straight.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using

```
linear-gradient(#2396bf, #0d5b77 40%, #004961 3%, #004961);
```

And it even looks a little bit better